# Python: Display an entire div from a webpage in python flask webpage

Tags: python, html, flask

I am new to webscraping and working with flask in Python. I have created a search page with python and flask, I am able to save the string entered in the search bar in a python variable and print it (just to make sure it works). However, I want to run the word entered in python through a webpage, for example: `https://<url of webpage>/explore?query= + searchWord` where `searchWord` is the text entered by the user.

Running the search provides the results that are displayed in a `div` with `id=searchResults'`. My question is, is it possible to display that entire `div` in my flask webpage.

My python code for my search page is as follows (and it does display the search page):

```
from urllib import request
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests
from flask import Flask, render_template, request


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def home():
    errors = []
    results = {}
    if request.method == "POST":
        # get word that the user has entered
        try:
            searchWord = request.form['search']
            print(searchWord)

            #run a search and display the div code here.
            #not sure what to do.

             #EDIT:
             URL = 'https://visualgenome.org/VGViz/explore?query=' + searchWord
             page = requests.get(URL)

             soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')
             results = soup.find(id='searchResults')

        except:
            errors.append(
                "Unable to get URL. Please make sure it's valid and try again."
            )

    return render_template('search.html', errors=errors, results=results)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

This is my `search.html` page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<style>
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}

* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

form.example input[type=text] {
  padding: 10px;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  float: left;
  width: 80%;
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

form.example button {
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #2196F3;
  color: white;
  font-size: 17px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  border-left: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

form.example button:hover {
  background: #0b7dda;
}

form.example::after {
  content: "";
  clear: both;
  display: table;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<h2>Web Service</h2>

<form class="example" method="post" action="/" style="margin:auto;max-width:500px">
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search.." name="search2">
  <button type="submit" name="submit"><i class="fa fa-search"></i></button>
</form>

<br>


</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: This is an image of the how the div searchResults looks like:
[Div Structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jgoW2.png)

Comment: Just put the result in a variable and create a div having the variable. `<div id='searchResults'> {{ results }}</div>` You can also format as you desire. Please comment if I was unable to understand your concern.

Comment: @RandomCOSMOS Hi, unfortunately, that did not work. I added extra code to the python code above under `#EDIT` . When I added the code you mentioned above to the HTML, I only get `{}` printed. So I want to display the results after searching a word from the `visual genome dataset` at this [link](https://visualgenome.org/VGViz/explore). So basically I search a word on my html page and parse the text to the search bar of the mentioned link and return the results on my html page.

Comment: If you can, double-check that results actually has some content before you call render_template. Also, one other thing - Flask uses Jinja as its default rendering engine. Jinja and Flask auto-escape HTML, so it would render as plain-text. You should be able to put {{results}} anywhere on your page like the first comment says, but you'll want to mark it as actual HTML (and say its safe to render) by using {{results | safe}} instead. I'd first verify that results actually has data when it gets passed to render_template, though.

Comment: I am not actually familiar with `BeautifulSoup` but I think the problem might be that you don't have a div with an id in your `search.html`. Also, make sure `page.content` have the data you desire before assigning it to results.

Comment: @Joseph Hi, So I tested that out by `print(result)` and all it displayed was this `<div id="searchResults" style="min-height:800px;"></div>` which I know is incorrect as the `searchResults` id has additional `divs`. On the other side, as an alternative, would making use of `iFrame` allow me to only display a part of the webpage? What would be your suggestion?

Comment: Also - the main issue here is likely that you're passing an object, which the rendering engine can't really do anything with. It sounds like you're wanting to render the results from the search page as HTML - you'll need to get the HTML content as a string from the BeautifulSoup object. You should be able to do that by adding a new variable - html_results = str(results), and change render_template to render_template('search.html', errors=errors, results=html_results).

Comment: @James try converting the results to a string first and see if that helps. I don't have a ton of experience with BeautifulSoup, but I believe the results object will only contain the parent div - it might give you the full content when converted to a string.

Comment: @RandomCOSMOS Hi, I did check and page.content does contain the whole HTML of the webpage including the results in the `searchResults` div. And no problem, Thank you for your time.

Comment: @Joseph Unfortunately converting it to a String also did not do the job, it still printed out `<div id="searchResults" style="min-height:800px;"></div>` . I am considering using `iFrame` to embedd the resulting webpage to my HTML code?

Comment: An iFrame wouldn't help much, I don't think - it would render out either the entire webpage from a URL, or only the HTML you give it (which would have the same problem you're running into now with no elements under the searchResults div). Can you print page.content and post the searchResults div here with some of its internal HTML? Make sure to use the HTML in page.content not just the HTML you get when you load the page in your browser, as the content might change depending on browser headers (lots of sites will hide content if you try to scrape it instead of using a browser)

Comment: @Joseph I see. I will try that, because I am supposed to create a web service with Python, to query and visualise the visual genome dataset, provided in the link above, but the APIs of that dataset only allow me to work with an image id instead of a text based search, so I am trying run the query through the main visual genome dataset page and display the results.

Comment: @Joseph I have added an image of the searchResults div with some of its internal HTML. Also when printing page.content, the entire HTML does get printed.